# UnicodeEncodeError when writing to CSV from JSON

Tags: python, json, csv, encoding

I'm getting the following error when attempting to write to a CSV using JSON:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "twitter_search_csv.py", line 25, in <module>
status['retweet_count'],
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 139: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
import requests
import urllib2
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
import csv

auth = OAuth1('', '', '', '')
url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23OpeningCeremony'

response = requests.get(url, auth=auth)

data = response.json()['statuses']

with open('olympic_search.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    f = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for status in data:
        f.writerow([
            status['id'],
            status['text'],
            status['created_at'],
            status['coordinates'],
            status['user']['id_str'],
            status['retweet_count'],
        ])
```

Comment: The doc (http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), has a big note dealing with this situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explicitly encode the field. Otherwise Python try to encode it using ascii encoding.

```
>>> print u'\u2026'.encode('ascii')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    print u'\u2026'.encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> print u'\u2026'.encode('utf-8')
…
```

---

```
f.writerow([
    status['id'],
    status['text'].encode('utf-8'), # <----
    status['created_at'],
    status['coordinates'],
    status['user']['id_str'],
    status['retweet_count'],
])
```

Comment: Only now, I get an AttributeError: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter_search_csv.py", line 22, in <module>
    status['retweet_count'].encode('utf-8'),
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: @Robᵩ, Your answer looks better than mine. Why did you delete it?

Comment: Thanks! That works. How did you know that "text" needed to be encoded?

Comment: @PatrickBeeson, I examined some sample tweets.json. Other fields seems have lower chance of having non-ascii characters.